# TclError in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So this is the code python doesn't seem to be too happy with me about:

```
def checkAnswer(self, clickedButton):
            self.valueOne = self.itemOne[self.component]
            self.valueTwo = self.itemTwo[self.component]

            if clickedButton == 'left':
                if self.valueOne >= self.valueTwo:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Smart Cookie!', 'That\'s correct!')

                else:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Oh No!', 'That\'s incorrect!')

            elif clickedButton == 'middle':
                if self.valueOne - (self.valueOne * 0.1) <= self.valueTwo <= self.valueOne + (self.valueOne * 0.1) and self.valueTwo - (itemTwoComp * 0.1) <= self.valueTwo <= self.valueTwo + (self.valueTwo * 0.1):
                    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Smart Cookie!', 'That\'s correct!')

                else:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Oh No!', 'That\'s incorrect!')

            elif clickedButton == 'right':
                if self.valueTwo >= self.valueOne:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Smart Cookie!', 'That\'s correct!')

                else:
                    tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Oh No!', 'That\'s incorrect!')


            showQuestion()


        tkinter.mainloop()
        showQuestion()

gui = ProgramGUI()
```

and this is the error I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Assignments\Assignment 2\FIddle.py", line 101, in <module>
    gui = ProgramGUI()
  File "C:\Assignments\Assignment 2\FIddle.py", line 99, in __init__
    showQuestion()
  File "C:\Assignments\Assignment 2\FIddle.py", line 60, in showQuestion
    self.lab11.configure(text = self.itemList[0]['Name'])
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1330, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1321, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".2531617022640.2531617023144"
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error at all, would very much appreciate it if anyone could identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`showQuestion()` is trying to modify a widget, but it is being called after the root window has been destroyed (eg: after `mainloop()` returns, which only happens when the root window has been destroyed). When the root window is destroyed, all other widgets are also destroyed.

Comment: You're an absolute star, Bryan, thank-you. That's gone and fixed it and sorted out a few more issues I was having!